# Finding matrix such that it has a given kernel.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields

Find matrix $A$ over $\Bbb Z_3$ such that $\ker A = \left\langle\begin{pmatrix}
  1\\
  2\\
  0\\
  1\\
  2\\
  \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
  1\\
  1\\
  1\\
  1\\
  1\\
  \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
  1\\
  0\\
  2\\
  1\\
  0\\
  \end{pmatrix}\right\rangle$.

I am confused by this problem. I guess I am not sure what the task is.
I know how to calculate $\ker A$ for a matrix but what is this telling me?  $\ker A$ means $Ax = 0$ but how do you proceed when you have the set of solutions like this instead of the matrix?

Thank you.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the matrix that you’re seeking? $\mathbb Z_3$ is the field of the matrix elements, not the space of matrices, so $A$ is not going to be an element of it.

Comment: Surely, you mean that $Ker A$ is supposed to be *spanned* by the vectors you mention. Is $A$ supposed to be a square matrix? I'm assuming yes.

As long as you are willing to do some brute force computation, what you can do is the following. Let the 3 vectors you mention be $v_1,v_2,v_3$ nad pick $v_4,v_5$ so that $v_i$ are a basis. Next, pick $u_i$ so that $u_1 = u_2 = u_3 = 0$ and $u_4,u_5$ are linearly independent. You can now find (unique!) $A$ s.t. $A v_i = u_i$. This $A$ will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Let $B$ be the matrix whose columns are the given vectors. Then you want to find a matrix $A$ satisfying $AB=0$, or equivalently $B^{\intercal}A^{\intercal}=0$. So the columns of $A^{\intercal}$ must be in the kernel of $B^{\intercal}$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I believe so. 
Let's say we want the matrix $A$ to have minimal # of rows. Knowing when matrix multiplication is defined we can say the matrix $A^{\intercal}$  will be 3x1 matrix (a b c d e). Now from matrix multipl. we can get to: $\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2\\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0\\
  \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 
0\\
0\\
0\\
 \end{pmatrix}$

After some work we are left with the result  $A^{\intercal} =  \begin{pmatrix} 
-2e - d\\
 0\\
e\\
d\\
e\\
 \end{pmatrix} $  

And after transposing that, we should get the matrix $A$ with minimal number of rows, yes?

Comment: Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Compute the kernel of $A$. What is its dimension?

Comment: Hmm, it's 0. How should I find the matrix with minimal number of rows then?

Comment: It's not $0$, its $4$. Try determining the kernel of $B^{\intercal}$ first.

Comment: Yes, I can see that. Just went to edit it now but you already responded:)

Comment: As for the dimension of $B^{\intercal}$, it is $2$.

Comment: Still not sure where I am headed with this. What do these dimensions tell me? Should the matrix $A$ have dimension 3 in the end because its kernel is spanned by those three vectors? So the minimal number of rows of the final matrix $A$ would be 2?

Comment: Exactly! And judging from your previous comment, you can find two rows that work :)

Comment: Thank you. Just to summarize it then.. I am going to need to do do the same thing as I did in the first comment here but instead of $3x1$ matrix I will use a $3x2$ matrix. Get to the matrix $A^{\intercal}$, transpose it and I am done?

Comment: Pretty much, yes. Generally, the rows of $A$ must span precisely the kernel of $B^{\intercal}$. So in this case you need $2$ rows.

Comment: I can now take the matrix $A^T$ with 2 collumns $\begin{pmatrix}  
a & f\\ 
b & g\\ 
c & h\\ 
d & i\\ 
e & j\\ 
\end{pmatrix}$
Now do $B^TA^T$ and I should get the final transposed product.
$\begin{pmatrix}   
a+2b+0+d+2e & f+2g+0+i+j\\   
a+b+c+d+e & f+g+h+i+j\\   
a+0+2c+d+0 & f+0+2h+i+o\\
   \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}  0\\ 0\\ 0\\  \end{pmatrix}$
After some computing:
 \begin{pmatrix}  
e+2d & j+2i\\
0 & 0\\
e & j\\
d & i\\
e & j\\
 \end{pmatrix} Does that seem alright?

Comment: Seems alright. Now just pick good $d$, $e$, $i$ and $j$ so that you get the desired kernel.

Comment: How exactly do I "pick" them? Isn´t it enought to say $d,e,i,j$ are all in $Z_3$?

Comment: No. For $e=d=i=j=0$ the matrix won't have the desired kernel. There aren't that many options though, so just try a few values and give it some thought.

Comment: So for instance $e=d=i=1$ and $j=0$?